# Page Break After Specific Number Of Rows

Tags: php, html

I am developing a voucher printing application that prints serial numbers and pins from a MySQL table and displays them in a page.

The php code displays two records per row..with being in a separate column i.e two columns displayed side by side
Due to the format of the page (two records per row)..i can not display each record in a seperate table. Rather all records are contained in a "general" table.

The voucher printing requires two rows to be displayed on each page.

I implemented a "page-break-after: always" style to each row not divisble by two, but page break is not showing. My code is shown below:

```
        $aray=array();
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res))
  { 
 $aray[]=$row;
  }
$nr_elm=count($aray);
$table='<table width=100%><tr>';
$nr_col=2;
if($nr_elm>0)
{ 
$p=1;//This is the row counter
for($i=0;$i<$nr_elm;$i++)
{

    $table.='<td><div  style="border: 2px dashed #000;" ><div id="image" style="float:left;">
   '.$p.' <img src="crswb1.png" height=80 width=60 />
</div><div id="texts" style="  float: none;
margin-left:60px;"> 
   <p>&nbsp;Amount:'.$aray[$i]['amount'].' </p><p>&nbsp; Pin:17263648409</p><p>&nbsp; Serial:5374748548
</div></div></td>';

$col_to_add=($i+1)%$nr_col;
if($col_to_add==0)
{
    if($p % 2 == 0) {

      $table.="<tr style='page-break-after:always'>";

    }

    $table.='</tr><tr>';
    $p++;
            }
}

}

$table.='</tr></table>';
$table=str_replace('<tr></tr>','',$table);
echo $table;
     ?>
```

I viewed the page source and the "page break" style is showing for the neccessary row, as seen below

```
 <tr style='page-break-after:always'></tr><tr><td><div  style="border: 2px dashed #000;" ><div id="image" style="float:left;">
   3 <img src="crswb1.png" height=80 width=60 />
</div><div id="texts" style="  float: none;
```

How can i ensure that the page break is displayed so that i can print only two rows per page?..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the page does not prevent you to use one table for every two values. E.g. use the following HTML Code:

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>This is cell No. 1 in Table 1</td>
    <td>This is cell No. 2 in Table 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>This is cell No. 1 in Table 2</td>
    <td>This is cell No. 2 in Table 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

together with the following CSS Code:

```
@media print {
    table {page-break-after: always;}
    /* prevent blank page at end */
    table:last-of-type {page-break-after: auto;}
}

/* If you want the fields on one line */
table, tr {
    width: 100%;
    /* If the fields still don't fit on one line
     * make the font-size smaller */
    font-size: 0.9em
}
```

it will print one `table` per page. Notice that even the last table will cause a page-break.
To see this work I prepared a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/rqelibari/pen/aNdBJe). Open the codepen and try to print the page. You should see every `table` on it's own page.

Comment: They have to be side by side

Comment: I added CSS code, so the fields should appear on one line now.

Comment: @ewom2468: Please mark this answer as the accepted one if it helped you. Otherwise it would be nice if you'd explain why it did not help you.